# Weak nullstellansatz in Atiyah-Macdonald 5.17

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$\newcommand{\fm}{\mathfrak{m}}$
Problem 17 in the exercises after the 5th chapter of Atiyah-Macdonald is the following (with some references and hints omitted):

> Let $X$ be an affine algebraic variety in $k^n$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field, and let $I(X)$ be the ideal of $X$ in the polynomial ring $k[t_1,\dots,t_n]$. If $I(X) \ne (1)$ then $X$ is not empty.
>
> Deduce that every maximal ideal in $k[t_1,\dots,t_n]$ is of the form $(t_1-a_1,\dots,t_n-a_n)$ where $a_i \in k$.

The first part follows from the previous exercise, which consists of Noether normalization lemma and proves that $X$ has to surject onto $k^r$ for some $r \ge 0$. But I don't see how to *deduce* the second part from the first. If we start with a maximal ideal $\fm$, why is it $I(X)$ for some affine algebraic variety $X$? Since $\fm$ is maximal, and is contained in $I(V(\fm))$, it would be enough to show that $I(V(\fm)) \ne (1)$, but that seems to be equivalent to the required conclusion.

I can see how to finish after this, just let $(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in X$, and note that $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq (t_1-a_1,\dots,t_n-a_n)$, by repeated application of the remainder theorem.

Comment: Do you want to prove using Noether normalization? If it's so, see Gortz and Wedhorn book on Algebraic Geometry in the first chapter.

Comment: I know how to prove the first part using Noether normalization, but want to prove the second part using the first, if possible.

Comment: $(t_i -a_i)_i$ is always maximal, so it's equal to $\mathfrak{m}$

Comment: What is $a_i$ unless you already have $X$?

Comment: I thought this was our problem. So I have not got your question.

Comment: Oh, ok, now I think I've got it. $V(\mathfrak{m}) \neq \emptyset$, so $a_i$ is just the coordinate of the point.

Comment: Why is $V(\fm) \ne \emptyset$?

Comment: because it's an algebraic variety and you can apply the radical to the maximal ideal (strong Nullstellensatz).

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\m}{\!\mathfrak{m}}$Showing that $V(\,\m) \ne \emptyset$ (for an algebraically closed field $k$ and a maximal ideal $\,\m \subseteq k[t_1, \ldots, t_n]$) from first principles, is equivalent to the Nullstellensatz! Indeed the subtlety can be seen from the fact that it is no longer true if $k \ne \overline{k}$: e.g. $\,\m = (t^2 + 1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}[t]$ is maximal, but $V(\,\m) = \emptyset$.

Probably what Atiyah-MacDonald means is: use Noether normalization to deduce $\,\m = (t_i - a_i)$. To do this, notice that for any maximal ideal $\,\m$, $k[t_1, \ldots, t_n]/\m$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, hence by Noether normalization has a polynomial subring over which it is integral. But this subring must be $k$ itself (i.e. the polynomial ring in $0$ variables), so $k \subseteq k[t_1, \ldots, t_n]/\m$ is an integral extension. Since $k = \overline{k}$ and $k[t_1, \ldots, t_n]/\m$ is a field, we must have equality $k = k[t_1, \ldots, t_n]/\m$. If $\pi : k[t_1, \ldots, t_n] \twoheadrightarrow k[t_1, \ldots, t_n]/\m$ is the canonical projection, setting $a_i := \pi(t_i) \in k$ gives $(t_i - a_i) \subseteq \ker \pi = \m$, and then equality holds since $(t_i - a_i)$ is maximal.

Comment: I believe this proof is the one intended in exercise 19, which asks to deduce the same conclusion as 17, but from the fact that field extensions of finite type are finite extensions (which is included in your argument).

Comment: @ronno: I agree that Exercise 5.19 is in the same spirit as my argument. Nonetheless I believe this is what the exercise (5.17) intended. Are you looking for a different argument?

Comment: The wording _deduce_ would seem to imply that one can obtain the result as a consequence of the previous. And surely the two exercises should not have (essentially) the same solution.

Comment: Using a liberal definition of *deduce*, I'm not so sure I agree with your first sentence, and to be honest I agree even less with the second! By the way, essentially every proof of the Nullstellensatz I know, although starting with sledgehammers of different generality (e.g. Jacobson rings, Noether normalization, Artin-Tate), eventually reduces down to precisely this argument. In the end though, I can only say - good luck finding an alternative approach!